# Преобразовать формат даты в Databricks

Tags: python, spark

Использую `Datbricks`, 
нужно преобразовать время  `1/11/2022 1:00:55 PM` 
к виду `2022-01-11 13:00:55.905194.`

**Пробывала так:**

```
data = data.withColumn('EnqueuedTimeUtc', F.to_timestamp('EnqueuedTimeUtc', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a').alias("time").cast(TimestampType()))
```

но не срабатывает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65733807/how-to-change-string-column-to-date-time-format-in-pyspark

Comment: решение по ссылке не работает(